# Mips Merge Sort

Tags: assembly, mips, mergesort

I am trying to code a mergesort program using Mips but it is getting caught in an infinite loop and I can't seem to get it to work.

```
.text
.globl main

main:
addi $sp, $sp, -4
sw   $ra, 0($sp)
la   $a0, array
li   $a1, 3
li   $a2, 43
la   $a3, helper

jal  mergesort      #go through mergesort

move $a0, $v0       #move result to address $a0
li   $v0, 4     #print  out array
syscall

lw   $ra, 0($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 4
jr   $ra

li   $v0, 10        #finish program
syscall

mergesort:
addi $sp, $sp, 4    #save variables
sw   $ra, 0($sp)
sw   $s0, 4($sp)
sw   $a1, 8($sp)
sw   $a2, 12($sp)
sw   $s1, 16($sp)
sw   $s2, 20($sp)
sw   $s3, 24($sp)
sw   $s4, 28($sp)
sw   $s5, 32($sp)
sw   $s6, 36($sp)
sw   $s7, 40($sp)

slt  $t0, $a1, $a2  #comparing low < high
li   $t1, 1
bne  $t0, $t1, quit #if false finish program

add  $s0, $a1, $a2      #s0 = mid (mid = (high+low)/2)
sll  $s0, $s0, 1

j    mergesort_1    #first recursion
j    mergesort_2    #second recursion
j    merge      #start merge

mergesort_1:
move $a2, $s0       #mid = high
jal  mergesort      #go through mergesort with new parameters

mergesort_2:
add  $s0, $s0, 1    #low = mid+1
move $a1, $s0
jal  mergesort      #go through mergesort with new parameters
merge:
add  $s1, $s1, $a1  #s1 = i = low
add  $s3, $s3, $a1  #s3 = k = low
add  $s2, $s0, 1    #s2 = l = mid+1

add  $s4, $a0, $s1  #s4 = a[i]
srl  $s4, $s4, 2

add  $s5, $a0, $s2  #s5 = a[j]
srl  $s5, $s5, 2

add  $s6, $a3, $s3  #s6 = c[k]
srl  $s6, $s6, 2

while1:
slt $t0, $s0, $s1   #i <= mid
bne $t0, $zero, while2
slt $t1, $a2, $s2
bne $t1, $zero, while2  #j <= high
            #if either fails go to next while loop

add  $s4, $a0, $s1  #s4 = a[i]
srl  $s4, $s4, 2    
add  $s5, $a0, $s2  #s5 = a[j]
srl  $s5, $s5, 2

slt  $t2, $s4, $s5  #a[i] < a[j]
addi $t3, $t3, 1
beq  $t2, $t3, if_1     # if condition is true go through if statement

move $s6, $s5       #else, c[k] = a[j]
addi $s3, $s3, 1    #increment
addi $s2, $s2, 1

jal  while1     #go through while loop again

if_1:
add  $s6, $a3, $s3  #s6 = c[k]
srl  $s6, $s6, 2

move $s6, $s4       #c[k] = a[i]

addi $s3, $s3, 1    #increments
addi $s1, $s1, 1

jal  while1     #go through while loop again

while2:
slt  $t0, $s0, $s1  # if i > mid, end while loop
bne  $t0, $zero, while3

add  $s4, $a0, $s1  #s4 = a[i]
srl  $s4, $s4, 2    
add  $s6, $a3, $s3  #s6 = c[k]
srl  $s6, $s6, 2

move $s6, $s4       #c[k] = a[i]

addi $s3, $s3, 1    #increments
addi $s1, $s1, 1

jal  while2     #go through while loop again

while3:
slt  $t0, $a3, $s2  # if j > high end while loop
bne  $t0, $zero, for_init

add  $s5, $a0, $s2  #s5 = a[j]
srl  $s5, $s5, 2
add  $s6, $a3, $s3  #s6 = c[k]
srl  $s6, $s6, 2

move $s6, $s5       #c[k] = a[j]

addi $s3, $s3, 1    #increments
addi $s2, $s2, 1

jal  while3     #repeat while loop

for_init:
move $s1, $zero     #set parameters for for loop
add  $s1, $s1, $a1  #i = low

for:
slt  $t0, $s3, $s1  #if i > k end for loop
bne  $t0, $zero, quit

add  $s7, $a3, $s1  #s7 = c[i]
srl  $s7, $s7, 2

add $s4, $a0, $s1   #s4 = a[i]
srl $s4, $s4, 2

move $s4, $s7       #a[i] = c[i]

addi $s1, $s1, 1    #increment

jal  for        #repeat

quit:
lw   $s7, 40($sp)   #load values
lw   $s6, 36($sp)
lw   $s5, 32($sp)
lw   $s4, 28($sp)
lw   $s3, 24($sp)
lw   $s2, 20($sp)
lw   $s1, 16($sp)
lw   $a2, 12($sp)
lw   $a1, 8($sp)
lw   $s0, 4($sp)
lw   $ra, 0($sp)

addi $sp, $sp, 48   #return to main
jr   $ra    


.data
array:  .word 56,3,46,47,34,12,1,5,10,8,33,25,29,31,50,43
helper: .word 0:50
```

It was working yesterday, but for some reason I can't get it to work today and I have no idea what changed.

Comment: First line in mergesort should be addi $sp, $sp, -48    #save variables. I don't know MIPS, but I'm wondering how the code ever gets to mergesort2 or merge since I assume j ... is not a call or conditional branch.

Comment: @rcgldr You are correct. The `addi` is the bug. The inst could [also] be `subi $sp,$sp,48` [might be more compact]. `jal` ("jump-and-link") is equiv to x86 `call` inst. It stuffs the `$ra` reg with return address instead of stack push. `jr $ra` is equiv to x86 `ret`. It's only one reg/level. Thus, for recursion, notice `$ra` gets saved to the stack frame [and restored at fnc exit]. As you noticed, the `j` insts for [`mergesort_1`], `mergesort_2`, `mergesort_3`, and `merge` don't do anything--and they can be removed. These labels are hit due to "fall through" from 1 to 2 to 3 to merge.